# Blue Card Germany surname change after wedding

Tags: germany, blue-card

I have a German BlueCard and I need to change my surname due to marriage. I was advised to change my passport first which I have but I am not entirely sure what are the next steps to apply for a new blue card with the new surname and also to update the supplementary sheet (Green paper booklet). Where do I need to start first? Who should I get in contact with?

Comment: To your responsible immigration office, since they were the authority that issued your residence permit in the first place.